# Spring current session - how to get a user id

Tags: spring, security

I would like to get the id of the currently logged in user and use it to access their specific user page.

To implement that I have been able to get the current logged in user's name using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHomePage(Model model,  Principal principal, HttpServletRequest 

    request) {

    try {

        CustomUser customUser = 

            (CustomUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        request.getSession().setAttribute("name",
                customUser.getName());

        request.getSession().setAttribute("userId",
                customUser.getUserId());


        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", customUser);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "/main/home";
}
```

Then in the JSP page, I'm using the following code to try to get the user's page based on their id:

```
     <c:url value="/main/user/?userId=${user.userId}" var="url"/><a href="<c:out 

    value='${url}'/>">User Page</a>
```

But this implementation is not working. When I click on the user page, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:87)
org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:59)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2421)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:974)
com.project.myapp.dao.UserDAO.getUserByID(UserDAO.java:91)
com.project.myapp.dao.UserDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b394c410.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
com.project.myapp.dao.UserDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$232ac7e1.getUserByID(<generated>)
com.project.myapp.service.UserServiceImpl.getUserByID(UserServiceImpl.java:54)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
$Proxy314.getUserByID(Unknown Source)
com.project.myapp.controller.UserController.getUserPage(UserController.java:70)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I would like any insight into knowing why I cannot request the user's id but I can get the user's name.

Comment: It looks as though `${user.userId}` is not being resolved and the link is coming in with an empty userId. Can you see the URL the browser is using when you click the link?

Comment: Yes I can see it and the user id is empty, here it is - https://localhost:8443/**/main/user/?userId= . The userId is coming up empty and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Perhaps the userId is not being set by whatever retrieves your CustomUser. If you're using an implementation of UserDetailsService - worth checking to see how this is loading your CustomUser.

Comment: @WillKeeling, thank you that was what was missing. The userId was not set in the CustomUser class.